# Simple Intent - jUnit test fails

Tags: java, android, android-intent, junit

I am currently a bit puzzled about `Intent` extras.
I know that the so called extras are a `Bundle` and the `Bundle`
is internally a map.

And if I put something into this map, with `intent.putExtra("someName", "someValue");`, I expect that there is now a key called "someName" present in the map. But it isn't, according to my very simple unit test.

```
    public void testIntent(){
    assertTrue("true != true", true);
    assertFalse("false != false", false);

    final String extraName = "IamAnExtra";
    final String extraValue = "IamAValue";
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(extraName, extraValue);

    assertTrue("hasExtra==false", intent.hasExtra(extraName));
    }
```

Now ths results in the following:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: hasExtra==false
```

What kind of magic is happening behind the intent-code?
I know that it is normally working. Is the map cached and
written only if I send the intent? Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

I added the line `assertNotNull("extras == null", intent.getExtras());` which also fails.

And I checked the code from the methods `putExtra` and `getExtras`, which is:

```
    public Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
    }
```

and

```
    public Bundle getExtras() {
    return (mExtras != null)
            ? new Bundle(mExtras)
            : null;
    }
```

So if the member mExtras is null, then null is returned for getExtras.
But putExtra will create a new Bundle instance for `mExtras`, therefore
`mExtras` *should* not be null. I'm confused.

Comment: Are you running it as a _unit test_ or as a _instrumented test_? And what framework are you using, JUnit 4?

Comment: unit test. I used a normal TestCase.

Comment: I've thought that using a plain Intent is ok to use with good old unit, isnt it? I am not going to try to send it or something else.

Comment: Definitely it is not @JacksOnF1re, see my answer. I hope I could explain it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to test on the Android SDK using a normal `Unit Test`. Unit tests in Android should be used only for the app logic, using some mocking library like [mockito](http://mockito.org/) and plain Java code.

So you have to either mock that intent or implementing that test on a real device using an [Instrumented Test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html), option I strongly recommend.

You have the [explanation why here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-).

EDIT:

This gradle flag that the entry refers to:

```
    testOptions { 
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

only allows the test to be run without any warning exception, but does not makes you able to use the SDK. When you instantiate that `Intent` actually, you are getting nothing else but a null reference. In the end the assert `intent.hasExtra(...)` cannot be true.

Comment: Thank you jose, I will read every reference and test it myself tomorrow and accept the answer then.